# generate numbers in a new column after an event in another

Tags: r

I had asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387475/generate-numbers-before-an-event) and got the following solution which works perfect for generating negative numbers prior to an event.

```
   library(data.table)
   setDT(df1)[, event_lead:=-(.N:1) ,cumsum(event == 1)
     ][, event_lead := event_lead* (!event)]
   df1
   #    var1   var2 event event_lead
   # 1: 0.658 72.193     0         -5
   # 2: 0.641 70.217     0         -4
   # 3: 0.641 40.173     0         -3
   # 4: 0.652 52.687     0         -2
   # 5: 0.531 50.652     0         -1
   # 6: 0.529 39.497     1          0
   # 7: 0.651 29.291     0         -4
   # 8: 0.634 59.548     0         -3
   # 9: 0.711 51.925     0         -2
   #10: 0.635 75.772     0         -1
   #11: 0.710 53.378     1          0
   #12: 0.660 87.744     0         -3
   #13: 0.540 62.547     0         -2
   #14: 0.618 38.050     0         -1
   #15: 0.602 60.978     1          0
```

Now I'm trying to adjust this code so I get another column of positive numbers after an event.

```
    > setDT(df1)[, event_lead:=-(.N:1) ,cumsum(event == 1)
    +            ][, event_lead := event_lead* (!event)]


    > setDT(df1)[, event_follow:=+(1:.N) ,cumsum(event == 1)
    +            ][, event_follow := event_follow* (!event)]

    > df1
         var1   var2 event event_lead event_follow
     1: 0.658 72.193     0         -5            1
     2: 0.641 70.217     0         -4            2
     3: 0.641 40.173     0         -3            3
     4: 0.652 52.687     0         -2            4
     5: 0.531 50.652     0         -1            5
     6: 0.529 39.497     1          0            0
     7: 0.651 29.291     0         -4            2
     8: 0.634 59.548     0         -3            3
     9: 0.711 51.925     0         -2            4
    10: 0.635 75.772     0         -1            5
    11: 0.710 53.378     1          0            0
    12: 0.660 87.744     0         -3            2
    13: 0.540 62.547     0         -2            3
    14: 0.618 38.050     0         -1            4
    15: 0.602 60.978     1          0            0
```

Why does it skip 1 after `0` in `event_follow` and how can I fix that?

Comment: Which one is the input dataset

Comment: input is the same as [this first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387475/generate-numbers-before-an-event)

Comment: Thanks, so is that the expected output in `event_follow` or the one you got from the code and want to change.  If it is the latter, it is better to show the expected

Comment: oh ok, sorry about the confusion. `event_follow` is the one I got from the code and I need it to go `0, 1, 2, 3` (starting from lines `6` and `11`) rather than the `0, 2, 3, 4` it is currently giving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable by the `lag` of the logical vector (`event ==1`) and taking the `cumsum`, then multiply the sequence of rows with logical vector of 'event' and assign (`:=`) it to 'event_follow'.

```
df1[, event_follow := seq_len(.N) * !event ,cumsum(shift(event ==1, fill = FALSE))]
df1
#     var1   var2 event event_lead event_follow
# 1: 0.658 72.193     0         -5            1
# 2: 0.641 70.217     0         -4            2
# 3: 0.641 40.173     0         -3            3
# 4: 0.652 52.687     0         -2            4
# 5: 0.531 50.652     0         -1            5
# 6: 0.529 39.497     1          0            0
# 7: 0.651 29.291     0         -4            1
# 8: 0.634 59.548     0         -3            2
# 9: 0.711 51.925     0         -2            3
#10: 0.635 75.772     0         -1            4
#11: 0.710 53.378     1          0            0
#12: 0.660 87.744     0         -3            1
#13: 0.540 62.547     0         -2            2
#14: 0.618 38.050     0         -1            3
#15: 0.602 60.978     1          0            0
```

---

In the OP's post, 'event_follow' was created by using the cumulative sum of 'event' that is 1.  So whereever there is a 1, a new group starts.  If we check the output of

```
df1[, event_follow1 := +(1:.N) ,cumsum(event == 1)]
df1$event_follow1
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 1

which(df1$event ==1)
#[1]  6 11 15
```

the 6th, 11th and 15th are elements were the new sequence starts.  When we multiply with the new condition `event_follow* (!event)` i.e. the places where there are 1 in the 'event' are FALSE in the logical vector, so all those elements in 'event_follow' becomes 0.